# Checkbox not binding properly

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, model-binding

I'm having the following problem with my program:
I have a User class, which contains a collection of courses you can follow. The courses have a collection of trainingdays. I get all my values from a MySQL database. I am model binding my User class. Everything is model binding properly, but when I submit my selected trainingdays, it doesn't change the values to true.

**Updated:**
Switching to viewmodels made it so it sends back a empty viewmodel on clicking submit.

Classes:

```
public partial class User
{       
    /*insert User Properties*/
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    /*methods*/
}

public partial class Course
{
/*insert Course Properties*/
public virtual ICollection<Trainingday> Trainingdays{ get; set; }
public IEnumerable<Trainingday> GetTrainingdays()
    {
        IEnumerable<Trainingday> listDays = (from l in Trainingdays
                                                   where l.IsSelected
                                                   select l);
        return listDays;
    }
}

public partial class Trainingday
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
private CourseViewModel model;
public ActionResult Course(User user, string code)
{
    Course course = user.GetCourse(code); /*retrieves the course for specified code*/
    model = new CourseViewModel();
    model.Date = course.Date;
    model.Title = course.Title;
    model.Description = course.Description;
    model.Trainingdays = course.Trainingdays;
    return View("Course", model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Trainingdays(CourseViewModel courseModel)
{
    IEnumerable<Trainingday> trainingdays = courseModel.GetTrainingdays();
    return View("Trainingdays", trainingdays);
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class CourseViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Trainingday> Trainingdays{get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<Trainingday> GetTrainingdays()
    {
        IEnumerable<Trainingday> listDays = (from l in Trainingdays
                                                 where l.IsSelected
                                                 select l);
        return listDays;
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model Models.Domain.CourseViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Course";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Trainingdays","Course", new{Model}))
{
<table>
<tr><td>Date</td><td>Selection</td></tr>
@foreach (var item in Model.Trainingdays)
      {
          <tr>
              <td>
                  @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Date)
              </td>
              <td>
                  @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => item.IsSelected)
              </td>
          </tr>
      }
</table>
       <input type="submit" value="Show selected trainingdays!" />
  }
```

When I click submit, all my values remain the same as before.
I've been looking at this problem for a while now, and the solutions I find from other people don't seem to help.

Comment: Is the problem that your view model is a Course, and your Trainingdays method takes a User? The model binder binds values to properties based upon a naming convention, and I doubt that it's going to be using the right naming convention.

Comment: @Stengel Can you show us code for submitting your values ?? You have to call **context.SaveChanges** are you sure you are correctly submitting your values ??

Comment: I do not have a context.SaveChanges... Nor do I have a context. What context do I need to create in that controller?

I have a method SaveChanges in my UserRepository, do I need to create a UserContext then?

Comment: You are expecting single IsSelected for TrainingDays and view has multiple fields. ( same is the case with date field).  You could have form for each loop or you could change properties to hold multiple types.( use List<bool> SelectedIds )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **View** is strongly typed as `@model Models.Domain.Course`, but your POST method expect `User`. The default Model Binder build the whole model back in the server based on the type that each HTML Helper create each input or any other HTML element in the View, from the **Model**.

You are posting `Course` not `User`, so change the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Trainingdays(Course course)
{
  /*Do Stuff here*/
  return View("Trainingdays", trainingdays);
}
```

If you need any other properties to be displayed or posted you should create a ViewModel to encapsulate this, for exemple:

```
 public class CourseViewModel
 {
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public Course course { get; set; }
    /*Other stuff*/
 }
```

Then use it at the **View**:

```
@model Models.Domain.CourseViewModel
```

And receive it as **Action** parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoStuffWithCourse(CourseViewModel course)
{
  /*Do Stuff here*/
}
```

This way the default model binder will do the hardwork for you!

Comment: If I do that, my course has no values in it whatsoever. The title, description and the trainingdays are all null.

Comment: Then you should explain better what you need to post.

Comment: The viewmodel works up until I push submit. It sends an empty viewmodel back to my controller.

I want the Trainingdays Actionresult to select the trainingdays I selected. I'm really sorry if I'm not explaining things well, I'm still learning.

Comment: Thats what i explaned! Your method must receive the same type from the view!

Comment: I will get back on you when I get this viewmodel to work. I seem to have some difficulties with that too... My viewmodel isn't getting filled with values.

Comment: The viewmodel I am getting back after I push submit is a viewmodel filled with null values. I will update my first post.

Comment: Using this in conjunction with an EditorTemplate seems to have worked. Although some values that did not use the editor are null, I do not need them later on so all is well.

Thanks for the help!